# Gambler's Ruin variant: Play until the player earns target money

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I have a question that is a variant of Gambler's Ruin problem.

Setting: A wins a bet with probability $p\neq \frac{1}{2}$ and loses a bet with probability $q=1-p$. If A wins, A gets 1 dollar. Otherwise, A loses $1.

Suppose A starts with 0 dollar and whenever A has no money to bet (i.e., 0 dollar), A wins the bet with probability 1. The game goes on until the player A has $n$ dollars with him.

I am interested in finding the expected value of number of bets the player A need to play until the end of the game and the number of times the player A hit $0 during the game.

I managed to find the answer when $p=q=0.5$ to be $n^2$ by making the sample space to be $\{-n,...,-1,0,1,....n\}.$ However I don't think the same method can be used when $p\neq0.5$ and I am lost. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e_k$ be the expected number of bets starting from $k$ dollars. Then
\begin{align}
e_{k}&=1+pe_{k+1}+qe_{k-1},\qquad k=1,2,\dots,n-1\\
e_n&=0,\\
e_0&=1+e_1.
\end{align}
The first equation can be written as
$$
e_{k+1}-e_k=(q/p)(e_k-e_{k-1})-1/p
$$
Applying this over and over, you get
\begin{align}
e_{k+1}-e_k
  &=(q/p)^k(e_1-e_0)-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(q^i/p^{i+1})
\\&=(q/p)^k(-1)-\frac{1-(q/p)^k}{p-q}
\\e_{k+1}-e_k
  &=(q/p)^k\frac{2q}{p-q}-\frac1{p-q}
\tag{*}
\end{align}
Now, take equation $(*)$ and sum both sides from $k=1$ to $n-1$. The left hand telescopes to $e_n-e_1=-e_1$, and the right hand side can be simplified. This lets you solve for $e_1$. You can then sum $(*)$ from $k=1$ to $m-1$ to get a formula for $e_m$, for all $m$. The result is
$$
-e_1=\frac{2q}{p-q}\cdot\frac{(q/p)^n-q/p}{q/p-1}-\frac{n-1}{p-q}
$$
$$
e_1=\frac{n-1}{p-q}+2\cdot \frac{(q/p)^{n+1}-(q/p)^2}{(q/p-1)^2}
$$
$$
\bbox[5px, #ddddef, border: solid black 2px]
{e_m=\frac{n-m}{p-q}+2\cdot \frac{(q/p)^{n+1}-(q/p)^{m+1}}{(q/p-1)^2}}
$$
This is only valid for $m\ge 1$, but $e_0$ is simply $1+e_1$.

---

If $z_k$ is the expected number of returns to zero starting from $k$, then you instead have

\begin{align}
z_{k}&=pz_{k+1}+qz_{k-1},\qquad k=1,2,\dots,n-1\\
z_n&=0,\\
z_0&=1+z_1.
\end{align}
We are counting the number of times you move from $0$ to $1$, which is the same as the number of visits to zero. This is even easier to solve. You instead have
$$
z_{k+1}-z_k=(q/p)^k(z_1-z_0)=(q/p)^k(-1)\tag{**}
$$
Therefore, using a telescopic sum with $(**)$,
$$
-z_1=-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(q/p)^k\implies z_1=\frac{(q/p)^n-q/p}{q/p-1}
$$
$$
z_m-z_1=-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(q/p)^k\implies \bbox[5px, #ddddef, border: solid black 2px]
{z_m=\frac{(q/p)^n-(q/p)^m}{q/p-1}}
$$

Again, this assumes $m\ge 0$.

---

Let $B_{n,m}$ be the probability that starting with $\$m$, you hit $\$0$ before you hit $\$n$. This is the classical gambler's ruin problem, whose solution is well known to be
$$
B_{n,m} = \frac{(q/p)^n-(q/p)^m}{(q/p)^n-1}
$$
Letting $N$ be the number of times you reach zero before reaching $n$, then
$$
 \bbox[5px, #ddddef, border: solid black 2px]
{
P(N=k)=
\begin{cases}
B_{n,m}\cdot B_{n,1}^{k-1}\cdot (1-B_{n,1}) & k>0 \\
1-B_{n,m} & k = 0
\end{cases}
}
$$

Comment: Thank you. If I am interested in p.m.f of the number of times the player hits 0 dollar, how should I modify your answer? So suppose $N$ = the number of times the player hits 0 dollar, and P($N=k$)?

Comment: @jackDanielle See edit.